# Access files in Users/Library on Mac OSX using Python?

Tags: python, relative-path

Can somebody suggest me how do I access files/folders in Users/Library on Mac. I want to delete file in Users/UserAccountName/Library path. I used the command os.remove('~/Library/filename') but I get error IOError: 2, 'No such file or directory'. Can somebody help me in resolving this?

Comment: try changing your current working directory, and then delete the file without the path

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to run this script in various Mac systems. Hence, I'm trying to delete the files dynamically. Hence, changing the current working directory may not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't automatically expand strings such as `~` unless you explicitly request that behavior.

```
os.remove(os.path.expanduser('~/Library/filename'))
```